# Django dropbox dynamic error

Tags: django

I have a page that display all the objects acorrding to the catergory the students pick.
 I implemented a pagination on the site to split the objects at different pages.

The problem occurs when the students pick a catergory from the dropbox and tries to flick through the pagination for new and old entries.

[image]

The reason this happens because everytime the user picks a catergory from the dropbox , the dropbox get reset once it retrieve the objects. So when  users try to flick through objects using the pagination . The pagination doesn't know what data to retrieve because the dropbox catergory get reset and redirec the users to a blank page.

A solution to this is to program the dropbox to remain static for the choices the users make so when the users flicks through the data split by the pagination , the pagination know can retrieve objects according to the dropbox.

I can't figure out how to make this dropbox remain static for the choices the users make.

my views.py

```
def BoardFinder(request):
    form = BoardFinderForm(request.POST)
    fo = BoardFinderForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        Category = form.cleaned_data['Category']
        posts = Board.objects.filter(Category=Category)
        paginator = Paginator(posts, 1)

        try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
        except ValueError: page = 1

        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return render(request,"boardfinder.html",{"posts":posts,"fo":fo})
    return render(request,"boardfinder.html",{"fo":fo})
```

My models.py

```
class Board(models.Model):
    MATH = 'MATH'
    ENGLISH = 'ENGLISH'
    SCIENCE = 'SCIENCE'
    LANGUAGE = 'LANGUAGE'
    CATEGORY = (
        (MATH, 'Math'),
        (ENGLISH, 'English'),
        (SCIENCE, 'Science'),
        (LANGUAGE, 'Language'),
    )
    Category =models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=CATEGORY)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    picture = models.OneToOneField('Picture',related_name='picture',blank=True,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class BoardFinderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ('Category',)
```

Important parts of my boardfinder.html

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ fo.as_p }}
<input type = "submit" value= "Find WhiteBoard" />
</form>



            {% for post in posts.object_list %}
                <div class="title">{{ post.name }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET">
    <p><select name="category">
        <option value="" 
            {% if not request.session.category %}selected{% endif %}>
            (All subjects)
        </option>

        <option value="ENGLISH" 
            {% if request.session.category == "ENGLISH" %}selected{% endif %}>
            English
        </option>

        <option value="LANGUAGE"
            {% if request.session.category == "LANGUAGE" %}selected{% endif %}>
            Language
        </option>

        <option value="MATH"
            {% if request.session.category == "MATH" %}selected{% endif %}>
            Math
        </option>

        <option value="SCIENCE"
            {% if request.session.category == "SCIENCE" %}selected{% endif %}>
            Science
        </option>
    </select></p>

    <input type = "submit" value= "Find WhiteBoard" />
</form>

def BoardFinder(request):
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    if category:
        request.session['category'] = category
        posts = Board.objects.filter(Category=category)
        paginator = Paginator(posts, 1)

        try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
        except ValueError: page = 1

        try:
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return render(request,"boardfinder.html",{"posts":posts,"fo":fo})
    return render(request,"boardfinder.html",{"fo":fo})
```

Comment: I got to tell you something , the dropbox still get reset . lol

Comment: request session variable cannot be remove if it has a value. Try to show `{{request.session.category}}` if it has a value

Comment: self.fields['Category'].widget.attrs['value'] = '{{request.session.category}}' . Nope still wont work

Comment: no, we will not be using `BoardFinderForm`. Have you seen my answer, I create the form manually. And to test the value of the session, just put `{{ request.session.category }}` in the template not in the form

Comment: I got to go sleep seem it's 2am . Thank you very much for helping me today ,think of a game :]

Comment: yeah maybe tomorrow I will search for it. I'm busy posting here